# How to provide user and password in Impyla connection

Tags: python-2.7, python-module

I'm trying to connect to impala from python and using Impyla module for that purpose. Following is the code snippet used to connect.

```
connect(host='<impala_host>', port=21050)
```

This is failing with the Authorization exception, when I try to execute any query. Exact exception is,

```
impala.error.HiveServer2Error: AuthorizationException: User '<user>' does not have privileges to execute 'SELECT' on: <table>
```

How do I provide user and password to the connect method?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code it seems that the `user` and `password` parameters are set to `None` by default.  You should be able to just set them yourself using something like this:

```
connect(host='my.impala.host', port=21050, user='myuser', password='mypassword')
```

You can see the documentation here https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/blob/master/impala/dbapi.py.

Comment: I have the same problem but `user='myuser', password='mypassword'` does not help. I'm trying to connect on Windows, and `impyla` connects with my Windows account (OS username). Do you have any advice what to do? (I have to use Windows... :( Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The username can defined in cursor parameters, e.g.

```
conn = connect(host='myhost');
cursor = conn.cursor(user='myuser')
cursor.execute('select user();')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved it by adding use_ssl :

```
connect(host='my.impala.host', port=21050, user='myuser', password='mypassword', use_ssl=True)
```